# mysql pyramid initialise db generating invalid syntax with valid data

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, python-3.2

Ive made a pyramid app that works just fine using sqlite3. For production I need to use mysql.

In my initialize_db script I create a single user. Running the script yields the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)' at line 1") b'INSERT INTO auth_users (email_address, username, salt, password, is_staff, is_super, is_active) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)' ('stuff@gmail.com', 'admin', '1371576670.410974', "b'S\\x1a\\x12\\xab\\xa2a\\x12\\xffF~\\xd98\\xcd1\\xf4l'", 1, 1, 1)
```

However if I use the mysql shell this works fine:

```
INSERT INTO auth_users (email_address, username, salt, password, is_staff, is_super, is_active) VALUES  ('stuff@gmail.com', 'admin', '1371576670.410974', "b'S\\x1a\\x12\\xab\\xa2a\\x12\\xffF~\\xd98\\xcd1\\xf4l'", 1, 1, 1);
```

the auth_user's table looks like:

```
class User(Base,BaseExtension):
    __tablename__ = 'auth_users'
    id              = Column(Integer,Sequence('user_seq'), primary_key=True)
    email_address   = Column(String(255))
    username        = Column(String(50))
    salt            = Column(String(20))
    #password        = Column(Unicode(40))
    password        = Column(LargeBinary(17))
    is_staff        = Column(Boolean)
    is_super        = Column(Boolean)
    is_active       = Column(Boolean)
```

The new user is created like:

```
        super1 = User('sheena.oconnell@gmail.com','some_password_that_gets_salted_and_md5ed')
        super1.username = 'admin'
        super1.is_active = True
        super1.is_super = True
        super1.is_staff = True
        DBSession.add(super1)
        super1.groups.append = UserGroup('super')
```

I'm running Python3.2 and using [mysql for python 3](https://github.com/davispuh/MySQL-for-Python-3) as a driver.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For now I'm going to go with: That driver is broken.

Using oursql for python3 works fine.